# Which algorithm to detect errors in 32bit data with 8bit parity

Tags: algorithms, coding-theory

I want to transmit a 32bit message in eight groups of 5bit each. This leaves me with 8bits to use for error checking.

Overall, a group is likely transmitted without error, but when there is an error transmitting a group, there are probably multiple bits wrong.

If I use one parity bit per group, I have a 50% chance to detect a wrong group. But I don't need to know which group of a message is wrong, I want to check the entire message.

I want 100% chance of detecting if one group of the message is incorrect, regardless of how many bits are flipped in that group. If possible, I also want to be able to check wheather two neighboring groups have been switched.

Which algorithm should I use for error checking / How should I code the data?

Comment: Can you make your error model more precise? What guarantee should your code have?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I added a bit more detail, although I'm not sure how much error checking I can expect

Comment: I'd look for a code, not an algorithm. But for *two neighboring groups have been switched*, this looks like the standard case for a [block code](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_code). *Two groups switched* can be viewed as a *burst error* of twice the length of a group (eight or ten bits, depending how you look at it) - $n$-bit [burst error-correcting code](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burst_error-correcting_code) with $n$ check bits doesn't look promising.

Comment: Given the errors you're interested in, it might be better to think of your message as 8 symbols from an alphabet of size 32. It is a pity that 5 doesn't divide 32 – otherwise you could have used a linear code over a field of size 32.

Comment: You can construct explicitly a code able to detect (but not correct) one error greedily. Each codeword you choose rules out at most $1+31 \cdot 8 = 249 < 2^8$ other messages. Since you want $2^{32}$ codewords and there are $2^{40}$ messages, the greedy procedure will succeed. The numbers are small enough that you can in principle use this brute force construction.

Comment: If you also want to detect switching of neighboring groups, then each codeword you choose rules out at additional $7$ messages, for a total of $249+7=256$, so once again the greedy procedure will succeed.

Comment: The fact that the numbers *just* agree leads me to wonder where this question came from.

Comment: If you just want to be able to detect one error, pass the message in the first seven groups, and let the eighth one be their XOR. This gives you 35 message bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of your message as seven 5-bit numbers $x_2,\ldots,x_8 \in \{0,\ldots,30\}$. This gives you $7\log_2 31 \approx 34.68$ message bits. Calculate $x_1 = -\sum_{i=2}^8 ix_i \bmod{31}$, so that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^8 ix_i \equiv 0 \pmod{31}.
$$

It is easy to check that every single symbol error is detected, since $31$ is prime.

Now suppose that $x_i$ and $x_j$ are switched, but the equation above still holds. Then $ix_i + jx_j \equiv ix_j + jx_i$, and so $(i-j)(x_i - x_j) \equiv 0$, implying that either $i = j$ or $x_i = x_j$.